# Swift 4.2 Custom font Automatic Resize

Tags: ios, uilabel, swift4.2

in my swift App, I am trying to scale my font to the user preferred font scale and it doesn't seem to work.

When I try with the default font it works

```
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
```

with my custom font, I do the following and it doesn't work

```
        label.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .headline).scaledFont(for: UIFont(name: "Futura", size: UIFont.labelFontSize!))
```

Comment: Do you add "Futura" font in plist file?

Comment: Yes I did and still it doesn't work

Comment: Which iOS you run app? UIFontMetrics only on iOS11+

Comment: I Run iOS 11+ on the simulator